# Displaying notification after successful async redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to figure out the best way to display a `sweetalert` message after a successful async action. So I have an `ExcursionDetail` component that allows you to book the excursion. Here is the simplified component:

```
class ExcursionDetails extends Component {
    bookExcursion() {
        const userId = jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('token')).sub;
        this
            .props
            .actions
            .bookExcursion(userId, this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    render() {
        ....
        <RaisedButton label="Book Excursion" onClick={e => this.bookExcursion()}/>
        ....
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {excursion: state.excursion}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(ExcursionActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExcursionDetails);
```

The action creator:

```
export const bookExcursion = (userId, excursionId) => {
    return (dispatch, state) => {
        dispatch(requestBookExcursions())
        return ExcursionApi
            .bookExcursion(userId, excursionId)
            .then(resp => {
                if (resp.ok) {
                    return resp
                        .json()
                        .then(payload => {
                            dispatch(bookExcursionsSuccess(payload.data));
                        })
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                dispatch(bookExcursionsFailed(err));
            })
    }
}
```

What would be the best practice to then display the sweet alert notification? The options I thought of were:

- Add a `bookSuccess` property that I can view if true or false in my `ExcursionDetails` component and if true call the sweetalert function.
- Create notification specific actions and reducers and listen for it in my components. Only issue with this is I would need to have some sort of setTimeout after every notification call to clear the notification reducer and this seems a bit hacky.
- call the sweet alert function within my reducer
- pass a callback to the action creator
- `redux-thunk` returns a promise; however even if the http call fails it will return a successful promise so this option doesn't seem viable.

Comment: The only one I would definitely rule out is calling it from the reducer. You may also want to explore middleware as an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would and is using the first option that you mentioned.
I have created a new component and pass the redux store using connect. I check for it if the value is true on componentWillReceiveProps and set the state according and then you can display your sweetalert.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can call it in the action creator.

You can use something like [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).

Simple and clean.

```js
     export const bookExcursion = (userId, excursionId) => {
        return (dispatch, state) => {
            dispatch(requestBookExcursions())
            return ExcursionApi
                .bookExcursion(userId, excursionId)
                .then(resp => {
                    if (resp.ok) {
                        return resp
                            .json()
                            .then(payload => {
                                dispatch(bookExcursionsSuccess(payload.data));
                                //Here is your notification.
                                toastr.success('Have fun storming the castle!', 'Miracle Max Says')
                            })
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    dispatch(bookExcursionsFailed(err));
                })
        }
    }
```